# If $V:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is $C^1$ and positive definite does its level curves form a continuum around the origin?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

Let $V:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable and positive definite. I'm currently reading a book where the authors claim that $V$ has a continuum of closed level curves around the origin. While I certainly find this to be plausible it is not immediately evident to me. How is this proven? If the proof is extensive a simple sketch will suffice and I will do my best to fill in the gaps.

Note that in this context $V$ being positive definite means that $V(\textbf{0})=0$ and $\textbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{\textbf{0}\}\Rightarrow V(\textbf{x}) > 0$.

Comment: Mind defining "continuum of curves"?

Comment: Is it something like, $\exists$ neighborhood $B \ni \mathbf{0}$ such that if $V^{-1}(c) \subset B$ then all $V^{-1}(d)$ with $d<c$ are contained in $B$, and each is a closed curve?

Comment: Something along those lines I suppose. The authors gave no strict definition.

Comment: Closed curve (i.e. topological $S^1$) is probably true close enough to the origin. Do you already know how to do something simpler: Show that there is some $c>0$ such that $V^{-1}(c)$ is compact.